# use `prettier-plugin-svelte` in a sub folder project

Tags: svelte, prettier-vscode

I have about 3 hours, adjusting configurations and reloading VS Code with no solution to my issue. Obviously I am doing something dumb and found it's time to make it public, while asking for help...

here is my current project's tree:

```
.
|-- cmd
|-- internal
|   `-- server
|   # lots of other stuff.... 
|-- .prettierrc.yml
`-- spa
    |-- .eslintrc.yml
    |-- .gitignore
    |-- .prettierrc.yml
    |-- jsconfig.json
    |-- package.json
    |-- node_modules
    |   |-- @eslint
    |   |-- @sveltejs
    |   |-- eslint -> .pnpm/eslint@8.47.0/node_modules/eslint
    |   |-- eslint-config-prettier -> .pnpm/eslint-config-prettier@8.10.0_eslint@8.47.0/node_modules/eslint-config-prettier
    |   |-- eslint-plugin-svelte -> .pnpm/eslint-plugin-svelte@2.33.2_eslint@8.47.0_svelte@4.2.1/node_modules/eslint-plugin-svelte
    |   |-- prettier -> .pnpm/prettier@3.0.3/node_modules/prettier
    |   |-- prettier-plugin-svelte -> .pnpm/prettier-plugin-svelte@3.0.3_prettier@3.0.3_svelte@4.2.1/node_modules/prettier-plugin-svelte
    |   |-- svelte-preprocess -> .pnpm/svelte-preprocess@5.0.4_postcss@8.4.28_pug@3.0.2_sass@1.66.0_stylus@0.55.0_svelte@4.2.1/node_modules/svelte-preprocess
    |   # lots of other stuff.... 
    |-- src
    |   |-- app.svelte
    |   |-- index.html
    |   # lots of other stuff.... 
    `-- vite.config.js
```

My main project is using go. Among other things a simple SPA will be served by it, and we decided to put server's and spa source code all together in a single folder as shown above. The golang part is large but removed as irrelevant for this situation. The `spa` folder above lists the relevant files for the issue.

To brief the issue:

If I go the the root and run `code .`, I have access to the whole code (go and svelte). However `.svelte` files do not prettify on save (the prettier label on vscode shows disabled)

If I run `code spa` from root or `cd spa && code .` then prettier works nicely for svelte files, but I do do not have go code available.

Now focus!!!! I am not asking on how I should organize my tree. And I know I can create a VScode workspace that will "virtually" open `spa` on its own root and solve my problem.

The question is how to make svelte/prettier to work when inside a sub folder.

I have enabled prettier debug mode, and got this when running `code .`:

```
["DEBUG" - 1:24:38 PM] Using bundled version of prettier.
["DEBUG" - 1:24:38 PM] Enabling Prettier for Workspace /home/gustavo/project
```

and `svelte` is not added to `languageSelector` array.

When running `code spa`:

```
["DEBUG" - 1:54:23 PM] Local prettier module path: '/home/gustavo/project/spa/node_modules/prettier/index.cjs'
["DEBUG" - 1:54:23 PM] Using prettier version 3.0.3
["INFO" - 1:54:23 PM] Using config file at '/home/gustavo/project/spa/.prettierrc.yml'
["DEBUG" - 1:54:24 PM] Enabling Prettier for Workspace /home/gustavo/project/spa
```

and `languageSelector` array now includes `svelte` on it.

as you can see on above tree, I already copied my `.prettierrc.yml` to the root without success.

its content, by the way:

```yaml
printWidth: 120
tabWidth: 4
requirePragma: false
overrides:
    - files: ["*.md"]
      options:
          proseWrap: never

plugins: [prettier-plugin-svelte]

svelteIndentScriptAndStyle: false
# svelteSortOrder: options-markup-styles-scripts
svelteStrictMode: false
svelteAllowShorthand: true
svelteSelfCloseElements: "always"
svelteBracketNewLine: false
```

In the past I already had a similar issue with eslint. That was solved with a `.vscode/settings.json` file on my project's root adjusting its path. But, after reading `prettier` and `prettier-plugin-svelte` documentation, I do not see anything similar to do.

So... what am I missing in here?